# Finding a Recurrence Relation for a binary string with n digits that do not contain 000

Tags: recurrence-relations, binary-operations

Consider binary strings with $n$ digits (for example, if $n=4$, some of the possible strings are 0011, 1010, 1101, etc.)

Let $z_{n}$ be the number of binary strings of length n that do not contain the substring 000. Find a recurrence relation for $z_{n}$.

I've looked at alternative solutions for the same case but with ternary strings and bit strings but I've failed to draw an understanding of how to solve this problem. Please help!

Comment: Could you give more details how the pattern looks like ?

Comment: isn't a bit string same as a binary one?

Comment: That's all the information the question provides, sorry!

Comment: @coffeemath when I looked it up online it said they differed! But I was also quite confused so I am not 100% certain.

Comment: Well, your quoted part of the question (with the examples given) makes it clear what it is desired to count. So whether one calls them bit strings or binary ones doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 1):

A good string can only start with 1, 01, 001 and after any of these it becomes the same question but one has to add 1,2, or 3 to the count.

This approach can be made into a recurrence but I'll leave that to you.

Edit: no adding to the count is appropriate, since e.g. a string starting with 1 gives f(n-1) strings for that case, etc.